# WooCommerce: define and display groups of related products

Tags: woocommerce

I have a website where I need to show more than just one section of related products on the product page, ie. there would be a group of related products with the heading "Accessories", another group with the heading "Spare Parts", and another group with the heading "Additional Kits".

What I need help to do:

1. I want to be able to select and add products in the "Product Data" box (the same way you do with upsells and cross-sells).
2. How to make these chosen groups of products appear on a single product page.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks so much.